# Rails override validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to see not valid value in validation message.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :event, :scope => :user_id
```

Result: "Title has already has been taken"
I want: 
"Event #{event} already has been taken by #{user}"

i'm trying do this way, bun not working:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :event, :scope => :user_id, :message=>"#{self.event} already has been taken by #{self.user}"
```

Comment: I assume 'event' is another activemodel class?

Comment: Just for example. not in real project

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the ActiveRecord source code comment:

> The values :model, :attribute and
>   :value are always available for
>   interpolation The value :count is
>   available when applicable. Can be used
>   for pluralization.

So you can simply write your message as

```
validates_uniqueness_of :event, :scope => :user_id, 
                        :message=>"{{value}} is already taken"
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to make the `%{model}` output a space-separated model name instead of the model name with only its first letter capitalized? ie. RocketScience prints out as Rocketscience, but I'd be satisfied with either Rocket Science or rocket science when using `%{model}` in my interpolation.

Comment: @mkelley33 use this answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392648/4010391 to point message to a lambda, then you can interpolate `self`, which will return the reference to the model.

Answer (score 7):

Use a lambda, but at least in more recent versions of Rails, ActiveRecord will try to pass in two parameters to that lambda, and it needs to account for them. Using a simpler example, let's say we want to ensure a username only contains alphanumeric characters:

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[a-z0-9]+$/i, 
    :message => lambda{|x,y| "must be alphanumeric, but was #{y[:value]}"}
```

The first parameter passed to the lambda is an odd not-so-little symbol that would be great for telling a robot what went wrong:

```
:"activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.username.invalid"
```

*(In case you're confused by the notation above, symbols can contain more than just letters, numbers, and underscores. But if they do, you have to put quotes around them because otherwise `:activerecord.errors` looks like you're trying to call the `.errors` method on a symbol called `:activerecord`.)*

The second parameter contains a hash with the fields that will help you "pretty up" your error response. If I try to add a username with punctuation like "Superstar!!!", it will look something like this:

```
{
  :model=>"User", 
  :attribute=>"Username", 
  :value=>"Superstar!!!"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, actually in Rails 3.x it is neither %{{value}} nor {{value}} but %{value}.

Answer (score 5):

use a lambda :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :event, :scope => :user_id, :message=> lambda { |e| "#{e.event} already has been taken by #{e.user}"}
```