# devise email validation message dont show the attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to customise the devise validation message for my user model, the uniqueness column is email.

Currently the error message that is shown is `Email has already been taken`, i want to show a message like `Trial account already assigned for this email`. I don't want the attribute key to be shown in the error message and want to display a custom message.

below are a few things i have tried from posts i have checked, the closest i have got so far is this

i tried to update the `en.yml` like below

```
  activerecord:
      user:
        email: ''
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: 'Trial account already assigned for this email'
```

But the issue with above code is with rails form helpers, this also does not show label when field is email, it blanks out the label name.

I have also checked other posts on SO like

[Rails override validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167651/rails-override-validation-message) -- add multiple validation messages for email since i have validatable module

I also found anther alternative as mentioned here [Where can I change the "Email has already been taken" error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006270/where-can-i-change-the-email-has-already-been-taken-error-message/9006433)

```
activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "Trial account already assigned for this email"
```

but this seems to override taken for all models, I want to only override it for the user model.

Any help on how to achieve this would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a cleaner solution out there, but one thing you could do is:

In your `RegistrationsController`, override `create` to access the user model after initial validation

```
  def create
    super do |u|
      override_taken_error(u)
    end
  end
```

(See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L16)

Then, implement `override_taken_error` to remove the `:taken` error from the `:email` attribute, and add a custom error to the `:base` attribute:

```
user.errors.add :base, t('Trial account already assigned for this email')
```

The downside is that the error would not be directly tied to the email field. But at least you can make a reusable `override_taken_error` – you could even use it in an ActiveRecord lifecycle hook, like `after_save` or something.